# Can I conditionally attach a file to CC.NET status email dependant on the build result?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

We send out emails for any build status.  If the build fails I want to either:

- send an additional email with an attachment
- conditionally attach an file to the email

Either one works for me, but the second option is better I think.

How can I do that in the CC.NET config file?

Can I have two  sections - one with  and another with

Perhaps  is what I want, but I can't find an example of that.

Right now the config file looks like:

```
<publishers>
    <buildpublisher>
      <sourceDir>...</sourceDir>
      <publishDir>...</publishDir>
    </buildpublisher>
    <buildpublisher>
      <sourceDir>...</sourceDir>
      <publishDir>...</publishDir>
    </buildpublisher>
    <xmllogger />
    <email from="..." mailhost="..." mailhost Username="..." includeDetails="True">
        <users>          
          <user name="..." group="..." address="..."/>
        </users>
        <groups>        
          <group name="buildstatus" notification="Always" />
        </groups>
        <xslFiles>
          <file>xsl\header.xsl</file>          
          <file>xsl\modifications.xsl</file>          
        </xslFiles>        
      </email>
```

I am guessing I should add

```
<onfailure>
 <attachments>
  <file>...</file>
  </attachments>
 </onfailure>
```

I'm looking for a definitive example of some configuration that shows a publisher sending an email with an attachment for a filed build.

Answer (score 3):

from ccnet 1.5 onwards , you have the conditional publisher :
http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Conditional+Publisher

Comment: Thanks - but how does one match the condition with the publishers to execute?  Is it just by order?

Comment: Yikes - we're running version 1.0.1.1277 based on the dashboard I see.

Comment: <tasks>
...
</tasks>
<publishers>
 <conditionalPublisher>
   <conditions>
    <condition>Failure</condition>
    <condition>Exception</condition>
  </conditions>
  <publishers>
    the publishers you want on these states
  </publishers> 

  < other publishers>
</publishers>

you can add multiple conditional publishers
(did not try, but should work)

Comment: the xml view is not that ok, but if you copy the above into an xml editor, you get the idea :-)